# Static or dynamic linking when #import abc.exe in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, com, static-linking, dynamic-linking

Does the .exe get statically linked or dynamically linked when #import abc.exe is used in c++?

The question is whether it is required to have abc.exe in the location of executable created by class which is having #import abc.exe to link dynamically?

Comment: Are you using [MSVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=msvc-170)?

Comment: Yes. I m using MSVC

Comment: #import will just create C/C++ header and implementation files for C/C++ clients COM consumption, from a type library, assuming the type library is embedded a a Win32 resource in the .exe file. A type library is a binary file containing metadata describing the COM objects in question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/com-dcom-and-type-libraries. At runtime, the location of the COM server implementing the COM objects is not necessarily related to the .exe containing the type library (although it's often the same).

Comment: Also note that the functions you are calling through COM interfaces are generally neither exported from the implementing module, nor do they need to be imported by the consuming module. A COM server only needs to export a factory function that's used by the system to service requests to create objects of a given CLSID. A consumer need not link against that factory function either. That's all handled by the system.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Neither. #import will import the typelibrary (binary representation of COM types/interfaces) from that exe. Once your program starts it will start abc.exe (if registered properly) and your process will make inter process calls (RCP) to abc.exe using the COM infrastructure. And abc.exe doesn't have to be in your path, but it must have been registered with windows using abc.exe /RegServer (the information to find abc.exe will end up in the registry)

Comment: so it is required to have the abc.exe in the installed location of the executable which refers to it(as #import abc.exe) right?

Comment: @KasunWickramasinghe no `abc.exe` needs to be in the location where it registered itself  (assuming self registration).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you could refer to the Doc: [#import directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-import-directive-cpp?view=msvc-170)

> Used to incorporate information from a type library. The content of the type library is converted into C++ classes, mostly describing the COM interfaces.

That lets you import information from a type library.

> `filename` is optionally preceded by a directory specification. The file
> name must name an existing file. The difference between the two syntax
> forms is the order in which the preprocessor searches for the type
> library files when the path is incompletely specified.

Comment: This does not even begin to address the question that was asked.